# How do you append a specific data value to a dataframe at regular loc intervals using a loop? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a messy dataset that contains a value that occurs every 24 rows in the 'df' dataframe, and I want to append this value to a blank dataframe, called 'mk_result'.

There are a total of 93 values, and this value corresponds to a specific location in my 'location1' dataframe:

```
df.head()
Unnamed: 0  Mann-Kendall Trend Test Analysis    Unnamed: 2
0   User Selected Options   NaN NaN
1   Date/Time of Computation    ProUCL 5.17/13/2021 2:03:53 PM  NaN
2   From File   correct_F2SL_analysis_a.xls NaN
3   Full Precision  OFF NaN
4   Confidence Coefficient  0.95    NaN

locations1.head()
Unnamed: 0
7   RESULT-as-01
31  RESULT-as-02
55  RESULT-as-03
79  RESULT-as-04
103 RESULT-as-05

mk_result = pd.DataFrame()

x = 23
for item in locations1:
    mk_result = mk_result.append(df.loc[x], ignore_index = True)
    x=x+24

mk_result.head()
Mann-Kendall Trend Test Analysis    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 2
0   NaN M-K Test Value (S)  -1.0
```

As you can see, the loop that I created is only appended the first value, and not every other value after it.

Is there a way to change this so it appends all of the values?

Comment: `for item in locations1` iterates over the _columns_ of `locations1`. There's only one column in `locations1` and therefore only one `append`.

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  If you really want to take every 24th row out of a dataframe (starting at 23, as per your non-functioning code), you can simply do `mk_result = df.iloc[23::24]`.  So clearly, you want some additional functionality. Please describe it clearly.

Comment: @PierreD Yes this was the result I was looking for. The mk_result = df.iloc[23::24] code did the trick. I will be more descriptive and concise with reproducible examples in the future. Thank you!